# VBA macro to insert row after text found

Tags: vba, excel

I have followed some answers here in a bid to perform the task above, and found that the most suitable code for my task is the following:

```
Option Explicit

Const strText2 As String = "FUNDS"

Sub ColSearch_DelRows()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Dim cel1 As Range
    Dim cel2 As Range
    Dim strFirstAddress As String
    Dim lAppCalc As Long
    Dim bParseString As Boolean

    'Get working range from user
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Please select range to search for " & strText1, "User range selection", ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address(0, 0), , , , , 8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'Further processing of matches
    bParseString = True

    With Application
        lAppCalc = .Calculation
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Set cel1 = rng1.Find(strText2, , xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, , False)
    'A range variable - rng2 - is used to store the range of cells that contain the string being searched for
    If Not cel1 Is Nothing Then
        Set rng2 = cel1
        strFirstAddress = cel1.Address
        Do
            Set cel1 = rng1.FindNext(cel1)
            Set rng2 = Union(rng2.EntireRow, cel1)
        Loop While strFirstAddress <> cel1.Address
    End If

    'Further processing of found range if required
    If bParseString Then
        If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
            With rng2
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
            End With
        End If
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = lAppCalc
    End With
End Sub
```

Now the problem with the code here is that when it finds two consecutive rows (with the search query - funds),  it inserts two blank rows after the first one, and null after the second.

Can someone help me in finding the problem in this code?
The line where I am inserting the new row is: `.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert`

Thanks

Comment: The Insert method will insert as many rows as the range you apply it to involves. If you want to insert one single row after the first row of the range you apply it to, you may want to do .offset(1,0).Entirerow.rows(1).Insert

Comment: I have tried that instead, but it does insert a row after only one of the results of the search (for the string "funds".)  The problem of the solution above is probably related to the order of the events i am assuming.

Comment: Can you clarify what the expeted result actually is? I kind of tried to read between the lines but obviously I am missing something here. Maybe provide a visual example showing the rows before / after inserting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something here, but it sounds like your goal is to:

1. Prompt the user for a range
2. Find the cells in that range with the value "FUNDS"
3. Make the text of those cells bold
4. Insert a row below each instance of "FUNDS"

The below will do that:

```
Option Explicit
Const searchstring As String = "FUNDS"

Sub ColSearch_DelRows()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim ACell As Range

'Get working range from user
On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Please select range to search for " & searchstring, "User range selection", ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address(0, 0), , , , , 8)
On Error GoTo 0
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For Each ACell In rng1
    If (ACell.Value = searchstring) Then
        ACell.Font.Bold = True
        ACell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next ACell

End Sub
```

Comment: works exactly as I desired.   Thanks for the explanation and the code.

Comment: The text "Funds" is in Column B, and in Column A I have the dates.  If I were to ask, in the new row that is being added, can I dynamically copy the date and the string from the row above.  (The reason here is so that I can separate bank charges). 
I tried the following code after the row insert.  `ACell.Offset(1,0).Value = searchstring`.  However for some reason it is not working.   I was going to use the same offset reasoning to copy the date.   Should I ask a new question for this, kindly advise.  Thanks :)

Comment: Nevermind, the reason for the error I described in the above was that the code kept infinitely looping the same thing (as it was finding the search query each time).  Thanks again for your previous help.

Comment: Exactly. You could try adding a second For Each loop to look for cells that are blank, where the cell above is "FUNDS", and then fill those in with "FUNDS"--unless there are likely to be other blanks in your data. Also, I noticed that my code has a slight problem that rng1 doesn't expand when you add the rows. That may need to be addressed.